# Call another app, and send data with package name Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I use:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
startActivity(intent);
```

To call another app, but i want to set data for it

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by set data? What type of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can help me :( but i found by myself :)

My code:

```
Uri location = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
intent.setPackage("package name");
startActivity(intent);
```